# Why chrome extension for Gmail not working?

Tags: chrome, gmail

After enabling Gmail integration on my org I expected the chrome extension to work with Gmail. Unfortunately, it's not working. The extension is installed successfully, but clicking on it with Gmail does not show the Salesforce panel.

What am I missing?

**[Installed chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce/jjghhkepijgakdammjldcbnjehfkfmha)**

Org Gmail integration

[image]

Gmail has no salesforce panel

[image]

Comment: Can you try re-installing chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

This extension will only work if you're using g suite from memory.
Please check [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce/jjghhkepijgakdammjldcbnjehfkfmha) Overview, which clearly states that this extension works only for **corporate** Gmail.

[image]